# Why is my new ID always "1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a parent-child relationship between two objects.

```
Parent :has_many :children
Child  :belongs_to :parent
```

When creating a new parent, in the same controller, I'm creating the child.

```
@mom = Parent.new
@child = Child.new
@mom.children << @child
```

That all seems to go okay, but this parent has one more attribute - this parent has a favorite child

```
@mom.favorite_child = @child
```

Seems like this should work, except let's say that this is the 61st child in the database, so it gets an ID of 61 (and I know this is happening, because when I check the database, the child record has an ID of 61). For some reason, when I assign the @child to the parent's "favorite_child" attribute, "favorite_child" gets set to "1" - when I need it to be set to "61".

Clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like parent needs something like

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
  has_one :favorite_child, :foreign_key=>'favorite_child_id', :class_name => 'Child'
```

Otherwise, it doesn't know it's a foreign key relationship, and you're trying to assign an object to an integer.

Comment: Oh, wait, I have my relationships backwards - I have the 'favorite_child_id' field as an attribute of the Parent class - but it should be the other way around somehow, because the foreign key belongs in the class with the 'belongs_to' declaration.

Comment: i added a foreign key specifier in the code.  i don't think you have it backwards

Comment: The Child does get added to the list of children, but the 'favorite_child_id' field is left blank now.

I almost think that in the Child class I need something like "belongs_to :parent_that_favors_me, :class_name => 'Parent' as well.

I'll keep plugging away, or do away with trying this line of thinking altogether. There must be a cleaner/smarter way to try to define this.

Comment: What if, instead of trying to define this in terms of a relationship, in the Child class there's a boolean attribute called "is_favored", and then the Parent, when looking for their favorite, could simply iterate through all their children until they find the 'favored' child - hey maybe a Parent even has more than 1 favored child. :P

I think that might actually work.